# Generate multiple Unique IDs using algorithm with single input string/pattern

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there any algorithm or api to generate multiple Unique IDs with single input string/pattern, so that if we input any of the resulted IDs , it should match the pattern/String(ie, we could validate the resulted IDs against input pattern/String)

Any idea?

Comment: MD5 + an index - match the MD5 part ?

Comment: I need ' multiple generated IDs will correspond to single pattern/input'. Is it possible with MD5

Answer (score 1):

You could use an insecure hash function.  Your "single pattern" could be a hash value.  Your multiple IDs could then be any input that gave that hash value when passed to the insecure hash function.  The hash function needs to be insecure so you can drive it backwards to generate new IDs.

For example, your hash could be just XORing all the bytes together.  If your single pattern is 0x2A, then any string that XORs to that value can be an ID.

You will need to judge how insecure the hash function needs to be depending on your needs.  There are plenty of cryptographically insecure hash functions, of varying degrees of reversibility, that you could use.

Comment: is there any java implementation?

Comment: That depends on what hash function you select.  Avoid the crypto hashes since they aren't easily reversible and are slower.  There are a lot of ordinary hashes around, like the FNV hashes.  It is up to you to judge how easy you want it to be for an outsider to generate a valid ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void saveTable(UUID h1, Object x,Hashtable ht)
 {
     if(ht.get(h1) == null)
     {
         ht.put(h1, x);
     }
     else
     {
         Object ref=h1;
         Object ref2=new Object();
         while(ref!=null)
         { 
             if(ref!=null)
             {
                 ref2=ref;
             }
             ref=ht.get(ref);
         }
         ht.put(ref2,x);
     }
 }

 static ArrayList loadTable(UUID h1,Hashtable ht)
 {
     Object x=ht.get(h1);
     Object ref=h1;
     ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
     if(ht.get(h1)!=null)
     {
         while(ref!=null)
         {
             if(ref!=h1)al.add(ref);
             ref=ht.get(ref);
         }

     }
    return al;
 }
```

Then in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Hashtable ht=new Hashtable();
    UUID h1=UUID.randomUUID();
    UUID h2=UUID.randomUUID();

    saveTable(h1, "this is",ht);
    saveTable(h1, "inefficient",ht);

    saveTable(h2, "but",ht);
    saveTable(h2, "saves",ht);
    saveTable(h2, "the day",ht);
    saveTable(h2, "at least",ht);

    Object[] al=loadTable(h1,ht).toArray();
    Object[] al2=loadTable(h2,ht).toArray();

    for(int i=0;i<al.length;i++)
    {System.out.println(al[i]);}

    for(int i=0;i<al2.length;i++)
    {System.out.println(al2[i]);}
}
```

Output:

```
this is
inefficient
but
saves
the day
at least
```

Ofcourse I used strings as targets and UUID as keys. You can use alter the methods to accept strings as keys and UUID as targets.

Comment: But can we make it  map h1 -> both 'aaa','bbb' ? that is i needed

Comment: Yes, you can but my example is very inefficient. Especially when you use many objects per key.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the answer above an idea is to use a hash table, make your own [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), or simply use [Object.hashCode()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29). However note that you must handle collisions somehow. This means that id´s are not always unique, and you must handle that case. Javas built in [hashTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) handles this as they compare the String entered if there are several strings that get the same id when entered.